# How do I disable hover color for href component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a website with MUI components, in the nav bar I have added href to the Tab elements

```
<Tab label={element} id={index} sx={{display: {xs: 'none', md: 'inherit'}}} 
  href={`#${navElements[element]}`} 
/>
```

So by default the Tab color changes to blue while hovering the mosue over it since it has href, now I don't want it to be blue, but instead white. How do I do that?

I have tried by adding style property, `textDecoration` with `none` as it's value, but nothing's changed.

`sx={{textDecoration: 'none'}}`

Comment: Have you thought about changing `color` property?

Comment: I did, didn' work.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use the Link component of MUI and add a specific CSS file with a rule like this:

```
a:hover {
  color: #fff; // here your white color
}
```

This is because Link components will be render as `a` tag.